# Is there a semantic error in my code that I'm missing?

Tags: python, math, calculus

I made a code to try and compute the partial sum of a series, but it keeps producing a result that's about 0.01 off. It looks pretty straightforward to me and I haven't been able to spot what my mistake might've been, but there's definitely something off.

```
import math
def f(n):
    s = 0
    for x in range(1,n+1):
        y = x*(4**x)
        d = (math.factorial(x))*(4**x)
        n = -1**x
        s += n/d
    print(s)

f(7)
```

Comment: What should the result be?

Comment: `-1**x` is always `-1`, due to the order of operations - you probably want `(-1)**x`.  What was the point of calculating `y`, since you don't use it anywhere?

Comment: Your `y` variable is not used in your code.

Comment: I disagree to say that this question is a duplicate. Correcting the pow call does not seem to be the solution.

Answer (score 1):

As written, your function computes a good approximation of `- (√√e - 1) ~ -0.28402541668774148407342056806244`.

By applying the fix suggested by jason, the constant is `1/√√e - 1 ~ -0.22119921692859513175482973302168`.

The discrepancy is larger than `0.01`. Given the abnormal assignment to `y`, we can suspect that you didn't post the right code.